# How to prevent players from updating their marker on Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript, arrays, tic-tac-toe, iife, revealing-module-pattern

I'm working on a Tic Tac Toe project and having trouble with a certain task.

> Build the functions that allow players to add marks to a specific spot on the board, and then tie it to the DOM, letting players click on the gameboard to place their marker. Don’t forget the logic that keeps players from playing in spots that are already taken!

Specifically the "Don't forget the logic that keeps players from playing in spots that are already taken!

I'm trying to see how to prevent the players from updating their marker from "X" to "O" and vice versa. I'd have to implement some sort of way to check if the cell is empty then don't update the array/board any more, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

```js
const Gameboard = (() => {
    "use strict"
    let gameboard = new Array(9).fill("");
    const setCell = (index, value) => {
        console.log({ index, value });
        gameboard[index] = value;
    };
    const resetBoard = () => {
        gameboard = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    }
    const getBoard = () => [...gameboard];

    return {
        getBoard,
        resetBoard,
        setCell
    }
})();

const displayController = (() => {
    "use strict"
    const board = document.querySelector(".board")

    const renderBoard = (arr) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            let cell = document.createElement("div")
            cell.id = i;
            cell.classList = "cell";
            cell.setAttribute("cell-data", i)
            cell.textContent = arr[i]
            board.append(cell)
        }
    }
    const clearBoard = () => {
        while (board.hasChildNodes()) {
            board.removeChild(board.firstChild);
        }
    }
    return {
        board,
        renderBoard,
        clearBoard
    }
})();
    
const gameController = (() => {
    "use strict"
    const playerFunction = (player, marker) => {
        return {
            player,
            marker,
        }
    }

    let player1 = playerFunction("Test1", "X")
    let player2 = playerFunction("Test2", "O")
    let isPlayerOneTurn = true
    const playerTurn = () => {
        if (isPlayerOneTurn) {
            isPlayerOneTurn = false
            return player1.marker
        } else {
            isPlayerOneTurn = true
            return player2.marker
        }
    }
    const boardEl = displayController.board;
    displayController.renderBoard(Gameboard.getBoard());
    boardEl.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if (e.target.classList.contains("cell")) {
            const index = e.target.getAttribute("cell-data");

            Gameboard.setCell(index, playerTurn());

            displayController.clearBoard();

            displayController.renderBoard(Gameboard.getBoard());
        }
    });
})();
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 10rem;
    font-family: 'Dongle', sans-serif;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
    justify-content: center;
}

.cell {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 70px;
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 100px;
    user-select: none;
    height: 100px;
}

.cell:hover {
    background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175, .5);
}

.cell:nth-child(1) {
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(2) {
    border-top: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(3),
.cell:nth-child(4),
.cell:nth-child(6) {
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(5) {
    border-top: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(7) {
    border: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(8) {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(9) {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="board"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you already have in place, you can read a cell's value with `Gameboard.getBoard()[index]`. If that is still the empty string (and thus not "X" or "O"), then it is OK to play at that index.

So you could add this statement:

```
if (Gameboard.getBoard()[index]) return; // Exit the handler without action
```

Here is your updated snippet:

```js
const Gameboard = (() => {
    "use strict"
    let gameboard = new Array(9).fill("");
    const setCell = (index, value) => {
        gameboard[index] = value;
    };
    const resetBoard = () => {
        gameboard = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    }
    const getBoard = () => [...gameboard];

    return {
        getBoard,
        resetBoard,
        setCell
    }
})();

const displayController = (() => {
    "use strict"
    const board = document.querySelector(".board")

    const renderBoard = (arr) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            let cell = document.createElement("div")
            cell.id = i;
            cell.classList = "cell";
            cell.setAttribute("cell-data", i)
            cell.textContent = arr[i]
            board.append(cell)
        }
    }
    const clearBoard = () => {
        while (board.hasChildNodes()) {
            board.removeChild(board.firstChild);
        }
    }
    return {
        board,
        renderBoard,
        clearBoard
    }
})();
    
const gameController = (() => {
    "use strict"
    const playerFunction = (player, marker) => {
        return {
            player,
            marker,
        }
    }

    let player1 = playerFunction("Test1", "X")
    let player2 = playerFunction("Test2", "O")
    let isPlayerOneTurn = true
    const playerTurn = () => {
        if (isPlayerOneTurn) {
            isPlayerOneTurn = false
            return player1.marker
        } else {
            isPlayerOneTurn = true
            return player2.marker
        }
    }
    const boardEl = displayController.board;
    displayController.renderBoard(Gameboard.getBoard());
    boardEl.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if (!e.target.classList.contains("cell")) return;
        const index = e.target.getAttribute("cell-data");
        if (Gameboard.getBoard()[index]) return;
        Gameboard.setCell(index, playerTurn());
        displayController.clearBoard();
        displayController.renderBoard(Gameboard.getBoard());
    });
})();
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 10rem;
    font-family: 'Dongle', sans-serif;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
    justify-content: center;
}

.cell {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 70px;
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 100px;
    user-select: none;
    height: 100px;
}

.cell:hover {
    background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175, .5);
}

.cell:nth-child(1) {
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(2) {
    border-top: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(3),
.cell:nth-child(4),
.cell:nth-child(6) {
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(5) {
    border-top: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(7) {
    border: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(8) {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(9) {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="board"></div>
```

Not your question, but don't forget to add logic that detects a win or a draw and act accordingly.

Comment: Hey trincot appreciate the answer, can you expand a bit more just want to make sure all my ducks are in a row before moving to the logic that checks for win/loss/draw. So
`if (Gameboard.getBoard()[index])` return is checking if there is a cell at the index then return and exit the function?

Comment: ...it checks what the content is of the cell at that index. The content can be either empty, an "X" or an "O". If it empty, that condition would be "falsy". If it is not empty, that condition is "truthy". So in the latter case the handler is exited without any action.